# Format Field to Days with VBA or SQL

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am building a table in MS Access using SQL, one of the columns has a duration in days. I understand that if I build a new table with a *Make Table Query*, the column format properties just have to be set to @"days". Is there a way to do this in the code?

```vb
Dim tbl As String

tbl = "SELECT [Table1].[Task], [Table1].[Duration], [Table1].[Date] " & _
      "INTO [" & all & "] " & _
      "FROM [Table1]"

DoCmd.RunSQL tbl
```

When this code runs the new table converts *Duration* field to dates. 
For Clarity: *all* is a variable name for the new table.

Thank you!!!

Comment: What is the original type of *Duration* and the desired type? Always helpful to see input and desired output data.

Comment: It's imported from excel as a number, and then the tables and queries it's used in it's formatted as a short date with @"days" to make it a duration of days. Does that help? When you make a new table access automatically switches back to short date format without the @"days" included. Since I'm making a new table name every time (the variable all), I can't preset the format on that table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do with DAO. Open the TableDef and set the *Format* property of the duration field.

But you wouldn't have to. To view the data, create a query or form to view the data, and apply the format to the field or textbox displaying the duration.

Or create a query for the export:

```
Select *, Format([Duration], '0') & ' days' As Days
From YourTable
```

or even:

```
Select *, Format([Duration], '0') & ' day' & IIf([Duration] = 1, "", "s") As Days
From YourTable
```

Comment: my next step is to export the table to excel, so the format needs to be in the table. I'll try using DAO...if you have the chance, could you type up what that code would look like?

Comment: Well, but then you would create a select query and use that for the export. In this query you can force a format on the output using an expression with Format. See extended answer, please.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working...can this sql string be run on its own to adjust formatting or does it need to be incorporated into the build of the table/

Comment: It is the SQL code of a select query. Of course, adjust table and field names to those of yours.

Comment: Dim fmt As String
   fmt = "SELECT [" & all & "], Format([Duration], @"days")" & _
           "FROM [" & all & "]"
           
   DoCmd.RunSQL fmt

Comment: ^this is what I'm trying to run, all is a variable name for the table, it comes up with an error

Comment: Try this with single quotes and correct spacing: `"SELECT [" & allField & "], Format([Duration], @'days') " & _ "FROM [" & allTable & "]"`. Or use the Format expression from my answer.

Comment: That gives me an error: syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Comment: Try with another format expression: `"SELECT [" & allField & "], Format([Duration], '@ days') " & _ "FROM [" & allTable & "]"`.

Comment: Format([Prev Tbl].[Duration], '0') & ' days' As Duration

Comment: ^ This one works! Incorporating this into my Select / Insert Into statement worked. Thank you!

Comment: do you know what would the format would be if I want the field to be 'short text' instead of a number?

Comment: You wouldn't. Always store numbers as numbers, then format if/as needed for display.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like;

```
Sub Format_Dates()
     Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-en-US]d-mmm-yy;@"
End Sub
```

"Selection" can be replaced by Range.NumberFormat.

(You would just need to find the date format you need. PowerSpreadsheets has a good article on this [found here "Excel VBA Date Format"](https://powerspreadsheets.com/vba-format-date/))

Comment: It's not Excel but _Access_ .. no range or selection here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just store it as a number.

If you want to output it as a date, use the DateAdd("d", num-days, base-Date)